# How to json_decode in custom PHP Extension.so

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I am building a custom PHP extension and want to be able to pass some functions a JSON object to be manipulated. In the `congif.m4` file I have this:

```
PHP_ARG_WITH([json],
  [for json],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-json],
    [Enable json support])],
  [no],
  [no])
```

At the top of my extension I have:

```
#include "ext/json/php_json.h"
```

My build script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
phpize --clean
phpize        
./configure   
make
cp /root/PHP-7.4.11/ext/new_module/modules/rdental.so /usr/lib/php/20170718/
service apache2 restart
```

How can I access the `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` functions? Can you give me an example of what that would look like such as this:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(test_json)
{
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_OBJECT(incoming_json)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    zval new_object;
    new_object=json_decode(incoming_json);
    if(new_object[0]=="test"){
       new_object[0]="new value";
    }
    RETURN_OBJECT(json_encode(new_object));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add the JSON extension as a dependency in your config file using the following autoconf macro: `PHP_ADD_EXTENSION_DEP(your-ext-name, json, true)`

Secondly, if you look at the `php_json.h` file you can see the following exported function definitions:

```c
PHP_JSON_API int php_json_encode_ex(smart_str *buf, zval *val, int options, zend_long depth);
PHP_JSON_API int php_json_encode(smart_str *buf, zval *val, int options);
PHP_JSON_API int php_json_decode_ex(zval *return_value, const char *str, size_t str_len, zend_long options, zend_long depth);

static inline int php_json_decode(zval *return_value, const char *str, int str_len, zend_bool assoc, zend_long depth)
{
    return php_json_decode_ex(return_value, str, str_len, assoc ? PHP_JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY : 0, depth);
}
```

Those functions allow you to call the underlying subroutines used by `json_encode/decode`